# Memory issue with PharData::buildFromDirectory

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a Wordpress plugin that requires to tar and gz the whole upload folder in the file system.

My Code:

```
try {
  $phar_data   = new PharData( $tar_path );
  $phar_data->compress( Phar::GZ );
  $phar_data->buildFromDirectory( $plugins_dir, '/.*(?<!gz)$/' );
} catch (Throwable $e) {
  error_log( print_r( $e, 1 ), );
}
```

I am getting this error in the debug.log.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36864 bytes)
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why my try / catch is not capturing this error?  I would like to handle this error or any other error in a better way.
2. It's clear that I don't have enough memory in the PHP process, but that's something I can't control.  It's there any solution to achieve the same task with minimal memory consumspion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

What taking memory is the compression operation.  I am seperating it out and compress it file by file.

```
$phar_data = new PharData( $tar_path );
$phar_data->buildFromDirectory( $path );
$this->gzCompressFile($tar_path);



protected function gzCompressFile($source, $level = 9){ 
    $dest = $source . '.gz'; 
    $mode = 'wb' . $level; 
    $error = false; 
    if ($fp_out = gzopen($dest, $mode)) { 
        if ($fp_in = fopen($source,'rb')) { 
            while (!feof($fp_in)) 
                gzwrite($fp_out, fread($fp_in, 1024 * 512)); 
            fclose($fp_in); 
        } else {
            $error = true; 
        }
        gzclose($fp_out); 
    } else {
        $error = true; 
    }
    if ($error)
        return false; 
    else
        return $dest; 
}
```